# why are this two flutter containers somehow related?

Tags: flutter

Coding in flutter:
I noticed that when changing the first container's (in the stack) height (the one with the 3 containers inside), the second container is fully visible if the size is smaller or partly cut at the bottom, if not invisible, if its size is bigger. I'm using the Stack to overlay the two containers. I'm also working on a website, rather than a mobile app.

I was trying to copy a layout like this one [carrd layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrUnX.jpg), where the pfp is overlaying several images.
This is the code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[100],
        elevation: 0, 
        title: Text('@someone', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontFamily: 'Nunito', color: Color.fromRGBO(119, 118, 121, 1))),
        shape: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(119, 118, 121, 1), 
          width: 2.0,         
        ), 
      ),
    ),
    body: 
    Stack(
      children: [

        Container(
        height: 250,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
    
            Container(width:200, height:100, color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 63, 62, 59)), 
            Container(width:200, height:100,color: Colors.amber), 
            Container(width:200, height:100, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 91, 183, 63)), 
      
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 80, 
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 50, 
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 130, height:130, decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
            child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 60, color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ], //children 
    ),

    );
  }
}
```

This is what i get when changing the circle's size to 200x200 (It's probably not centered properly, but this is what i get on full screen):
[what i get as a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFVEJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your Containers' size to fullfil your requirement.

Result:

[image]

Implementation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _profileContainerHeight = 150.0;
  final _profileContainerOffset = 30.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: _profileContainerHeight + _profileContainerOffset,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                  height: _profileContainerHeight,
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 63, 62, 59),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                  height: _profileContainerHeight,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                  height: _profileContainerHeight,
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 91, 183, 63),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 30,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - _profileContainerHeight / 2,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: _profileContainerHeight,
                height: _profileContainerHeight,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    size: 60,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ], //children
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Stack's size is determined by non-positioned children: the outter `Container`:

[image]